# iOS: Identifying source of virtual memory allocations

Tags: ios, memory-leaks

Using the VM Tracker instrument, I am seeing ever growing virtual memory use on my iOS app. The allocations that are growing do not show up in the regular Allocations instrument, and I'm wondering what's the process of identifying where they are coming from. The category that is growing is VM_ALLOCATE.

I've put a symbol breakpoint on vm_allocate to catch allocations of the specific size I'm seeing are leaking in instruments (using register $r2 for the size argument). However, I only see a few 4k allocations throughout the lifetime of the app (coming from debug NSLog calls), and none of the 1+ MB allocations reported in instruments.

Is the method I'm using to break on all allocations reported under VM_ALLOCATE in instruments the correct one? Any ideas what else I can try to identify the source of the growing allocations?

Answer (score 1):

Put a symbolic breakpoint on mach_vm_map.  That will get you some more, but perhaps not all.

See also http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-825.40.1/gen/magazine_malloc.c

Another possibility is that immediately adjacent VM allocations are shown in Instruments coalesced into a single block.  In other words, what Instruments is showing as a single large allocation might, in fact, be made up of many adjacent small allocations.  I have not yet verified this, though.